# VBA Add Formula To Cell with Named Region from another closed WorkBook (Run-time error '1004')

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I need Create new workbook (wbook) and fill data from current - it's not a problem.
I need add some data in wbook from another file (third).
I try do with VLOOKUP.

```
=VLOOKUP(RC[-2];'C:\Users\xxx\Documents\RH.xlsx'!RHr;2)
```

correct work in cell

```
wBook.Sheets(1).Cells(7, 9).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2];'C:\Users\xxx\Documents\RH.xlsx'!RHr;2)"
```

return Run-time error '1004'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, despite using the semicolon `;` as your list separators in your formula (as per your country settings) vba only takes commas `,` and converts them to `;` within the formula.

```
wbook.Sheets(1).Cells(7, 9).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'C:\Users\xxx\Documents\RH.xlsx'!RHr,2)"
```

Comment: Not working.
I'm sure something in this: 'C:\Users\xxx\Documents\RH.xlsx'!RHr

Comment: Rather than stating "Not working" which doesn't tell me anything, can you tell me what does and doesn't happen?

Comment: @VjatšeslavObmjotko Apologies I misjudged the problem. I've updated my answer and this should work.

Comment: thank you. I'm completely forget about comma, and that I use non US format )

Comment: No problem. Also [this website](https://www.excel-exercise.com/comma-or-semicolon-in-excel-formula/) helped me change my list separator settings to test my answer. Will help you set it to `,` instead if you're more comfortable with that.