# Generated formula gives error, but manually entered does not

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a script to sum values on different sheets. The code gives an error

> Run-time error '1004' on the final line

I tried to removed the equal sign on the first line so it's like this:

```vb
    Formula = "IFERROR($F38/(" 'Formula begins with =IFERROR($F38/(
```

And then manually adding the equal sign before the generated formula, and then it sums as expected.

```vb
    Formula = "=IFERROR($F38/(" 'Formula begins with =IFERROR($F38/(
    For x = 3 To Sheets.Count
        Formula = Formula & "SUMPRODUCT((" & Sheets(x).Name & "!$I$11:$I$10000=$D38)*1)+" 'Add SheetName and Cell and pluss
    Next x
    Formula = Left(Formula, Len(Formula) - 1) ' Remove trailing plus sign
    Formula = Formula & ");0)" ' Add final arguments for iferror
    Range("G38").Formula = Formula 'Where do you want to put this formula?
```

This is the generated formula (The value of the 'Formula' variable):

```
=IFERROR($F38/(SUMPRODUCT((Reg1!$I$11:$I$10000=$D38)*1)+SUMPRODUCT((Reg2!$I$11:$I$10000=$D38)*1)+SUMPRODUCT((Reg3!$I$11:$I$10000=$D38)*1));0)
```

Comment: Change the last part to use a comma not a semicolon: `Formula = Formula & "),0)"`

Comment: I would very strongly recommend not to use reserved words as your variable name (i.e. `Formula`)

Comment: [VBA accept only "," in formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58374349/vba-add-formula-to-cell-with-named-region-from-another-closed-workbook-run-time?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: replace ";" with ","!

Comment: @Rory Thanks, completely missed that.  Not quite sure how to mark this question as solved though.